# Using Samsung basic phone SM - B310E as a gsm modem to initiate call through PC using AT commands

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem

I want to use a basic Samsung phone SM- B310E as a gsm modem to initiate a call through AT commands from my pc. This phone can be connected to pc using the normal USB cable. But I don't know how can I make it work as a gsm modem.

Please tell how this can be achieved? If this is not possible then please tell any other way to achieve the same. I am using a non-Android phone.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: okay. thanks a lot